# Mongo golang cursor performace

Tags: mongodb, go

My question is this, we have a mongo database with a query that returns a large number of documents, somewhere in the 800 thousand, I have refined the query to return in under 2 minutes, but my problem is this, when I go to decode them into struct the process takes about 35 minutes.

Is there anything I can do to speed up that process, I noticed that while it's doing its thing my cpu is not using all that much maybe there is a way to max out the cpu to decode faster? or a quicker way at all?

snippet to show you what I am talking about

```
    cursor, err := s.db.Collection("visits").Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{etc..etc..})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("caught error running GetTransactionInfo aggregate, err %+v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("finished getting transactions from database!")
    err = cursor.All(ctx, &model)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("caught error running decoding GetTransactionInfo model, err %+v\n", err)
    }
    log.Println("finished decoding cursor into struct")
```

console output with timestamp

```
2021/07/23 18:18:37 finished getting transactions from database!
2021/07/23 18:53:18 finished decoding cursor into struct
```

As you can see the cursor.All step takes 35 minutes to finish. All the while my 8 core machine sat about 20% usage or less.

Now I have also tried this

```
for cursor.Next(ctx) {
  cursor.Decode(&modelSlice)
  model = append(model, modelSlice)
}
```

which takes roughly the same time to complete.

Comment: Since you are returning large number of documents from the server via the cursor, try to batch them - use `BatchSize` of `AggregateOptions` (of `Collection#Aggregate`). This might involve some trials with various sized batches and find one that is optimum for your use case.  I am assuming that the issue is other than decoding, may be memory related. Cursor is a pointer to the result set data on the server. When the query run is complete - the result is not returned to your application - just the cursor.

Comment: Okay I can try that, so your saying the cursor.All function is more memory related, as in if I have a lot of it (32gb machine), I should be able to set a large batch size? or are you talking smaller batches more like studio 3t where they return like 50 at a time?

Comment: "This might involve some trials with various sized batches and find one that is optimum for your use case.". I suggest batch size starting from 5 thousand...